# Вывод из mySQL timestamp в UNIX виде

Tags: php, mysql

В базе хранится дата и время в виде 2012-09-25 12:31:13.0 Правильно я понимаю, что на самом деле содержимое просто так отображается, но хранится в формате UNIX? Как мне вывести его в UNIX? Либо как перевести 2012-09-25 12:31:13.0 в секунды? На php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правильно я понимаю, что на самом деле содержимое просто так отображается, но хранится в формате UNIX?

Неправильно. Там своя структура хранения. Причем разная для `DATETIME` и `TIMESTAMP`

> Как мне вывести его в UNIX?

Вам нужна функция `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

> Либо как перевести 2012-09-25 12:31:13.0 в секунды?

Либо функция `TO_SECONDS()`

> На php.

`strtotime()`

Answer (score 2):

Ответ довольно прост

```
$time = strtotime('2012-09-25 12:31:13.0');
```

пример:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac42f317ccd3569445ef4498823cb8e9aa306cab

Comment: А можно сразу выводить в UNIX? Без перевода? (за ответ спасибо уже так сделал)

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин смотри ответ AntonShchyrov ниже та он написал что можно в mysql добавить to_seconds